# Download multiple data tables from a website

Tags: r, web, url

I am trying to read these five tables in R available through this Alzheimer's disease database. What would be the solution for this? If it was a csv file on the web, I could have read it as `read.table`, but how do you read undefined tables?

The tables I am trying to read are here: [Link](https://www.alzforum.org/mutations/search?genes=&diseases%5B%5D=145&keywords-entry=&keywords=#results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `rvest` and `xml2`:

First, open the page and identify the location of the table in question. In Chrome, for example, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, switch to the element tab and expand elements until the table is highlighted when you hover over the element:
[image]

Right click and choose "Copy XPath":

[image]

Now it's easy:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr) #for %>%
url <- "https://www.alzforum.org/mutations/search?genes=&diseases%5B%5D=145&keywords-entry=&keywords=#results"
my_xpath <- '//*[@id="results"]/article/div/table'
table <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath = my_xpath) %>% html_table()
table[[1]][1:10,1:4]
#   Mutation                 Clinical Phenotype              Pathogenicity                                                 Neuropathology
#1     A201V None, Parkinson's Disease Dementia        AD : Not Pathogenic                                                Not applicable.
#2     A235V                Alzheimer's Disease AD : Unclear Pathogenicity                                                       Unknown.
#3     D243N                Alzheimer's Disease AD : Unclear Pathogenicity                                                       Unknown.
#4     E246K                Alzheimer's Disease AD : Unclear Pathogenicity                                                       Unknown.
#5     E296K                Alzheimer's Disease AD : Unclear Pathogenicity                                                       Unknown.
#6     P299L                Alzheimer's Disease AD : Unclear Pathogenicity                                                       Unknown.
#7     R468H                               None        AD : Not Pathogenic                                                Not applicable.
#8     A479S                               None        AD : Not Pathogenic                                                Not applicable.
#9     K496Q                Alzheimer's Disease AD : Unclear Pathogenicity One reported carrier of this variant had autopsy-confirmed AD.
#10    A500T                               None        AD : Not Pathogenic                                                Not applicable.
```

Repeat the process as necessary to download the other tables.